# core-graphic subviews not cleared

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I have a UIView that consists of lines, shapes, text and graphic images.
This UIView is refreshed regularly by the app by re-drawing the entire picture.  However, when I do so the text, lines move to the correct new location, while the images are duplicated.  Clearing subviews does not seem to work.  Can anybody explain what I am doing wrong ?  Sample attached code shows an image that duplicates at every touch.

```
   class myMap2: UIView {

    var x_value: CGFloat = 100.0
    var y_value: CGFloat = 100.0
    var text_x = CGFloat(40.0)
    var text_y = CGFloat(220.0)

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        for view in self.subviews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()          // does not execute
            print ("removing a subview")
        }
        self.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() }) // still not clearing subviews
        let draw_context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextBeginPath(draw_context)
        onDraw(draw_context!)
        CGContextStrokePath(draw_context)
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:"didTap:")
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    }

    func onDraw(ctx: CGContextRef){

        let nRect = CGRectMake(text_x , text_y  , 250.0, 25.0)
        let font1 = UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 8.0)
        let nAttr = [
            NSFontAttributeName: font1!,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()]
        let normalLine = "Normal text line. flag at x: \(x_value) y: \(y_value)"
        normalLine.drawInRect(nRect, withAttributes:nAttr)
        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, text_x + 20, text_y + 20 )
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, text_x + 40, text_y + 80)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, text_x + 175, text_y + 120)
        let icon_layer = CALayer()

        icon_layer.frame = CGRect(x: x_value, y: y_value, width: 40, height: 40)
        let image = UIImage(named: "icon_red_flag")!
        icon_layer.contents = image.CGImage
        layer.addSublayer(icon_layer)
    }

    func didTap(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        x_value = x_value + 10
        y_value = y_value + 10
        text_x = text_x + 10
        text_y = text_y + 10
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

[![image after a few taps
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEeS3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEeS3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the matter by saving each layer in an array and then deleting each item in the array. Hope it helps somebody.

```
var layerArray = NSMutableArray()

layer.addSublayer(icon_layer)
layerArray.addObject(icon_layer)

for layer in layerArray {
    layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    layerArray.removeObject(layer)
}
```